# Managed bean passed via <ui:composition><ui:param> not found in <p:ajax listener>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets, managed-bean

I have a problem with the p:ajax component. I use a template and I transfer the managedBean as parameter.

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/formTemplate.xhtml">
<ui:param name="formBean" value="#{formFilm}"/>
```

When I use the managed bean into the template I works fine, but not into the p:ajax listener attribute.

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{formBean.completeCharacter}"/>
```

I get this error :

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'formBean' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier    
'formBean' resolved to null
```

It works into the view that uses the template. So how can I fix this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest?

Comment: I ve found a solution, the parameter declaration was bad. Into the marker metadata it works fine.     <f:metadata><ui:param name="bean" value="#{formFilm}"/></f:metadata>

Comment: Still, which JSF impl/version? Your initial attempt should namely just work (if templating is done right, of course).

Comment: I'm using the jsf version provided with glassfish 4.1. ( downloaded 2 weeks ago ) I don't know which version exactly, should be the 2.2. And i used the <ui:param> directly under <ui:composition>.